# How to use a variable of a class in another class without inheritance

Tags: java

I have a class named as veg_soup in java.I want to use variable 'che' in another class named as bill without using inheritance i.e. class bill extends class veg_soup.

now in the bill class I want to have bill amounted to che*100
please help.

Comment: pass it as a parameter

Comment: Without much more detail, we can't really help you. Based on what I think you're saying, you have at least two options: 1. When calling a method in `bill`, pass `che` in as an argument. 2. Make `che` a public field on `veg_soup` and have `bill` use that public field.

Comment: You're obviously free to use whatever conventions in your own code that you want, but when asking for help, please use the overwhelmingly-common conventions such as that class names start with an upper case character and are CamelCase (e.g., `VegSoup`, `Bill`). It makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: or 3: make a separate (singleton) class which both classes share. But given your (presumed) prior knowledge, go with option 1

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: sorry guys this was my first question.Appreciate the time you spent t help me

Comment: actually i had a problem including the source code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate in `veg_soup` to bill's class.

Note: veg_soup name is not a good practice for a name of a class. I will change it to 'VegSoup' and bill to 'Bill'

Sample:

```
public class VegSoup{
       public int amount che;
}
```

Instantiate VegSoup to Bill.

```
public class Bill{
     VegSoup vegSoup = new VegSoup();
     vegSoup.che = 100; // This way you can put 100 to che in Bill's class
}
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: your welcome. just click the check if my answer is right :)

Comment: your answer is right